# firebase:emulators:Start : The term 'firebase:emulators:Start' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-tools

I am trying to test my firebase project locally, so running this firebase emulators:start command showing me the error:

```
firebase : File C:\Users\Faizan Khan\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ firebase emulators:Start
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I have make sure that firebase-tools are installed.

If i run my html file directly in the browser then getting this error

> Access to script at
> 'file:///D:/@TLL_Projects/FireBase/TLLWebGLPortal/js/app.js' from
> origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests
> are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
> chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.
>
> indexFlex.html:68 GET
> file:///D:/@TLL_Projects/FireBase/TLLWebGLPortal/js/app.js
> net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: its showing erro like this firebase : File C:\Users\Faizan Khan\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ firebase emulators:Start
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 1):

run `firebase emulators:start` not `firebase:emulators:Start`

You could also specify wich service of the emulator you want `firebase emulators:start --only functions`

And here even attach your debugger to the emulator with this `firebase emulators:start --inspect-functions`

Comment: its showing erro like this firebase : File C:\Users\Faizan Khan\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1 + firebase emulators:Start + ~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess –

Comment: Try with something different than powershell